# OHLC Graph design

Tags: chart-design

I'm not sure if this is the correct website for my type of question, if it isn't please direct me to where it is. I want to graph an OHLC chart using some graphing software, now I know it is similar to a Candlestick chart, however my issue is the horizontal widths of the open and closes of the graph,

[image]

Plotting a Candlestick graph avoids these issues since the dimensions are calculated as a result of the y-axis (or the price), but in the above image, I am wondering if the prongs sticking out that are the Open and Close of the day are a function of the values or just a constant width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **don't** think this is a graphic design question. It *may* be closed as off-topic.

However, I just happen to work on projects containing candlestick charts regularly and often must redraw the chart data.

---

The horizontals on a candlestick are **consistent** and used indicate *where* in the trading range the close/open happen. There's no data conveyed by the *length* of the horizontals on a candlestick.

Some candlesticks will use stubby horizontals while others longer. And some candlesticks will use a wider bar to indicate the active trading range.. a la...

[image]

Green indicating up (open at the bottom) and red indicating down (open at the top).